# Parallel compression in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, gzip

I am trying to write a mapper program in Hadoop for parallel compression using gzip. How can I turn byte stream into a file in Hadoop?

Also, how can I use the arguments in main(`String[] args`)  to use the file path in mapper?

I know that there are compression codecs in Hadoop. But I think those codecs require using identity mapper and that makes the time to do the compression longer.

I read this paper about transcoding in Hadoop: http://www.sersc.org/journals/IJMUE/vol8_no2_2013/20.pdf. There should be a way to use byte stream directly from file in HDFS.
I tried using the code below. But, it results in `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException`.

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, 
            OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, 
            Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

    String line = value.toString();
    String filenameInput = "coba";
    String filenameOutput = "cobaOutput";
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    try {
        int len;
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

        Path filenameInputPath = new Path(filenameInput);
        Path filenameOutputPath = new Path(filenameOutput);

        FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(filenameOutputPath);
        FSDataInputStream in = fs.open(filenameInputPath);

        GZIPOutputStream gzipOS = new GZIPOutputStream(out);

        while((len = in.read(buffer, 0, 1)) != -1) {
            gzipOS.write(buffer,0,len);
        };

        gzipOS.close();
        out.close();
        in.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Why are you in a map method if you aren't using the key/value passed to it?

Comment: I think I should use map method to run the program in many computer

Comment: Can you post the code where you create an run this job?